# Обучение модели через Model Builder в Azure

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь обучить модель через Model Builder в Azure, а конкретно классификация изображений. Обучение начинается нормально, но спустя 30-40 минут появляется уведомление о том, что соединение прервано, при попытке нажать на кнопку "повторить", повторное соединение так же фейлится:

```
2022-01-25 16:31:19.0532 DEBUG Входная строка имела неверный формат.
   в AzureML.FailureCounter.<RecordFailureWithRetryWarningAsync>d__6.MoveNext() в /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/RemoteAutoML/FailureCounter.cs:строка 49
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в AzureML.AutoMLRunMonitoringImages.<MonitorParentRunAsync>d__1.MoveNext() в /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/RemoteAutoML/AutoMLRunMonitoringImages.cs:строка 145
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в AzureML.AutoMLRunnerImages.<RunAutoMLAsync>d__24.MoveNext() в /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/RemoteAutoML/AutoMLRunnerImages.cs:строка 190
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService.Experiments.AzureImageClassificationExperiment.<ExecuteAsync>d__14.MoveNext() в /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/Experiments/AzureImageClassificationExperiment.cs:строка 63
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLEngine.<StartTrainingAsync>d__21.MoveNext() в /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/AutoMLEngineService/AutoMLEngine.cs:строка 163 (Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.Utils.Logger.Debug)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете показать код, на котором вылетает данная ошибка?

Comment: там не код, а графический Model Builder

Comment: Я там вижу какой-то файл с конфигурацией, ещё `Program1.cs` вижу. Они связаны с процессом обучения? Если связаны, то покажите, вдруг там есть какая-то ошибка

Comment: ```// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");``` вот что в Program1.cs, а конфиг это и есть Model Builder графический, в текстовом виде не открывается. Program1.cs не связан с процессом обучения, а вот через  MLModel1.mbconfig - да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение: достаточно в настройка Windows сменить регион и формат региона на США, чтобы в разделителе стояли запятые, а не пробелы. Скорее всего баг Visual Studio